# trying to return atribute gives: PHP Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, laravel

This is a laravel project
Given the result of:

```
<? print_r($definition->term); ?>
```

It prints the following

```
            object(Term)#838 (5) {
  ["attributes"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(1124)
    ["term"]=>
    string(4) "test"
  }
  ["original"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(1124)
    ["term"]=>
    string(4) "test"
  }
  ["relationships"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["exists"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["includes"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
}
```

Im having trouble accesing the attibute "term" using

```
$definition->term->term
```

I get the following error: **Trying to get property of non-object**

How can I access the attibute term, to get the word test?
whats weird is that the code seems to run on php5.6, im having this problem just in php7

**------UPDATE------**

```
<? print_r($definition); ?>
```

prints:

```
        Definition Object
(
    [includes] => Array
        (
            [0] => term
        )

    [attributes] => Array
        (
            [id] => 21674
            [term_id] => 7060
            [definition] => this is a test
            [example] => this is an example
            [submitter_name] => asdf
            [approved] => 0
            [created_at] => 2020-05-26 16:39:31
            [updated_at] => 2020-05-26 16:39:31
            [votos] => 0
        )

    [original] => Array
        (
            [id] => 21674
            [term_id] => 7060
            [definition] => this is a test
            [example] => this is an example
            [submitter_name] => asdf
            [approved] => 0
            [created_at] => 2020-05-26 16:39:31
            [updated_at] => 2020-05-26 16:39:31
            [votos] => 0
        )

    [relationships] => Array
        (
            [term] => Term Object
                (
                    [attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 7060
                            [term] => test
                        )

                    [original] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 7060
                            [term] => test
                        )

                    [relationships] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [exists] => 1
                    [includes] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

        )

    [exists] => 1
)
```

This used to work to print the term **test**, now it does not:

```
{{ $definition->term->term) }}
```

This works

```
{{ $definition->submitter_name }}
```

Tried suggested answer `$definition->term->attributes['term'];` but it says  error: Trying to get property of non-object

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the `attributes` property and it's an array:

```
echo $definition->term->attributes['term'];
```

I don't know Laravel and you don't show the foreach loop that you mention in the comments, but the new object in your edit would be accessed like:

```
echo $definition->relationships['term']->attributes['term'];
```

Unless there are some magic `__get()` or something in the Laravel code.

Comment: Im getting an error: Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: With that `print_r` output that is the way to access it, something else is wrong.

Comment: Yeah its kinda weird, I tried as an array before with no success, even     print_r($definition->term->attributes); won´t work.

Comment: Is this from JSON or how are you getting the object?

Comment: Also, maybe in 5.6 error reporting/display is not enabled so you just don't see the error.

Comment: Thanks @abracadaver, the object comes from a foreach loop, I updated the question with more info.